# name for excel graph problem with the vba generator

Tags: excel, vba, charts

So I'm trying to use a name as range values to generate a graph chart. I used the code generator from excel and I got that :

```
Sub Macro_name_graph2()
'
' Macro_name_graph2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).name = "=""data1_1"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "==test_macro.xlsm!data1_1ord"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "==test_macro.xlsm!data1_1abs"
End Sub
```

what I put in the actual chart was `='test_macro.xlsm'!data1_1ord` and `='test_macro.xlsm'!data1_1abs`

But not when I try to run it again, I have an error 1004 at `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "==test_macro.xlsm!data1_1ord"`

So I tried to put `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=='test_macro.xlsm'!data1_1ord"` and it didn't work neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (changed the name of the workbook for my testing):

```vb
Sub Macro_name_graph2()
   With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "=Book1!data1_1"
        .Values = "=Book1!data1_1ord"
        .XValues = "=Book1!data1_1abs"
    End With
End Sub
```

Note the `NewSeries` method returns the added series, so you can use that return value in a `With` block.

Comment: it worked fine, thank you very much, is there way to turn the topic to answered?

Comment: @edwylin - by clicking on the checkmark to the left of this answer.